# Yahoo Finance API not showing real time quote price

Tags: python, api, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I am trying to get a stock price response however I am getting different results. Here is my attempt

```
import requests

url = "https://yahoo-finance-low-latency.p.rapidapi.com/v6/finance/quote"

querystring = {"symbols":"AAPL"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "xxx",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "yahoo-finance-low-latency.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Here is the [Documentation](https://rapidapi.com/finance.yahoo.api/api/yahoo-finance-low-latency). Basically, the script is the same as the template yet it is not showing minute-by-minute price data. I am expecting a response similar to this one ...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the chart API:

```
url = "https://yahoo-finance-low-latency.p.rapidapi.com/v8/finance/chart/AAPL"

querystring = {"interval":"1m"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "XXX",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "yahoo-finance-low-latency.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

api_result = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

api_response = api_result.json()
print(api_response)
```